# Google Analytics onClick Events Tracking not working

Tags: google-analytics, onclick, event-tracking

I have a series of links that I am trying to track as GA Events when the particular element is clicked. I've implemented this according to the guide here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide, but currently I can't seem to make the event trigger in Analytics. I've checked various other similar issues in this forum but I haven't been able to find a solution that works for me.

The code to one example is as below. The page itself can be found at http://www.300hours.com/offers.

Any help here would be much appreciated!

```
<a href="http://go.300hours.com/passedtense" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Offers', 'Passed Tense', 'passedtense',,false]);" target="_blank"><div class="span4"><img alt="Passed Tense" src="http://www.300hours.com/files/theme/FreeBanner.png" title="Passed Tense" style="z-index: 999999;position: absolute;top: -4px;height: 75px;width: 75px;right: -4px;"><div style="padding-top:10px; font-weight:bold;">Passed Tense</div><div class="media-centered media-centered-medium"><div class="media-centered-overlay"></div><img alt="Passed Tense" src="http://www.300hours.com/files/theme/Slide10.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" title="Passed Tense"><div class="title-block"><b>FREE mock exams &amp; quizzes</b><div style="font-size:12px;text-align: left;margin-left: 10px;font-style: italic;"><br><br>Custom Exams: Choose the difficulty level you want<br><br>Custom Quizzes: Choose the topic you need practice on<br><br>“Earned Level”: Guidance at your individual knowledge-level of the material</div></div></div><div style="text-align:center; font-size:12px;"><b>Try a new way of studying</b><br>  <div class="line-separator"></div><div class="offer-text">Our Adapt question bank is unlike other study material. It adapts to your personal understanding of the material so you can study at your own level and not receive questions that are too easy or too difficult - until you’re ready!</div></div><div class="wsite-button wsite-button-small wsite-button-normal reviews-offers-button" href="http://go.300hours.com/passedtense" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Offers', 'Passed Tense', 'passedtense',,false]);" target="_blank"><span class="wsite-button-inner reviews-offers-button-inner">Free Qbank (worth $199)</span></div></div></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see an error, _ga not defined.

Offers.html line 98.

M